# Who you gave your electric guitar to?

Tags: who

Who you gave your electric guitar to?

Is the above question grammatically apt?

Comment: It is nonstandard and ambiguous. Is "who" the recipient or the giver? 1. Who did **you give** the guitar to? 2. (FORMAL) To whom did you give the guitar? 2. **Who gave** you the guitar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not strictly correct but it is *ideomatic* (what a lot of native speakers would say). However it is not a *question* it is part of a *statement*. As @ParthShah says the question would be

> Who did you give your electric guitar to?

The strictly correct version would be

> To whom did you give your electric guitar?

But that would sound odd and old fashioned to many people.

The phrase you have given would be part of a *statement*, something like

> I bought this drum kit from the guy *who you gave your electric guitar to*.

Again it's not strictly correct but it is ideomatic.

Comment: It's "id**io**matic"

Comment: Thanks BoldBen. It's idiomatic and I have seen people use it that way

Answer (score 0):

The better way to write this answer is :

> Who did you give your electric guitar to ?

Comment: Definitely. However, checking if the above question grammatically right?